# How to use a variable to copy an entire column contents in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am assigning "c" as a variable and using it in a For statement. If Z1 = B1 or C1, I want it to copy the entire column.

I have tried:

```
Dim c As Range
Dim name As String

name = Range("Z1").Value

For Each c In Range("B1:C1").Cells
If c.Text = name Then
Columns.Range(c).Copy
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.

How do I work with variables that I have previously assigned in Columns/Range?

Comment: This is probably not the cause of your issue but you should avoid using internal VBA [Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement) statement as a variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very, very close:

replace:

```
Columns.Range(c).Copy
```

with:

```
c.EntireColumn.Copy
```

**EDIT#1:**

Once we have found the proper column, we can copy any portion of it.  Say we want to copy rows 17 through 23:

```
Dim kolumn As Long
kolumn = c.Column
Range(Cells(17, kolumn), Cells(23, kolumn)).Copy
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Let's say I still want to use "c", but I don't want the entire column - maybe from row 3 onwards? How would this be represented in code?

Comment: @scott  See my **EDIT#1**